# How to realize resource based authorization in asp.net core multi layer architecture?

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization

App - asp net core api.
We have entities - users and documents.
Each user is authenticated so I have userId in server side.
I have resource - document. Every document has author (userId). And we have action with document - sending, that author may perform.
I need to authorize current user as author of current document for sending.
So in all the guidelines I see recommendations like this:

```cs
[Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Send(int id)
        {
            var document = _documentRepository.Get(id);

            if (document == null)
            {
                return new NotFoundResult();
            }

            var authorizationResult = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, document, new MyRequirement());
            if (authorizationResult.Succeeded)
            {
                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                throw...;
            }
        }
```

But what if I dont want to get document? My general API-BL interaction like this:

```cs
[Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Send(int id)
        {
            await _documentSender.SendAsync(id);
        }
```

And where should I call AuthorizationService in my case? I need every time to call getter of document?

Comment: Resource-based authorization is (as the name says) to protect resources. "Sending a document" is no resource, so it doesn't apply there. What you are looking is ACL (Access-Control Lists) and there's nothing built in for that. If its per document, you first need to get the document to check it (or at a minimum a projection of your document with the relevant fields, read: Document ID and owner ID) and implement that in your own authorization service. Resource-based authorization is more for rest/crud-like API.

Comment: Using policy based authorization may be an option either, but you'd need to do db round trips in your policies which isn't necessarly a good thing (policy based authorization is good when you want to check if user has a specific claim to access some specific controller action). In many cases you have to fetch the resource anyways before mutating it (to see if the resource you are trying to send even exists in the first place), so you can apply the resource based policy on there.

Comment: Also in real world applications you need to get the data first before mutating it, to give meaningful http status codes back (404 when not found, 401 for when its belong to the user, 2xx when its okay, 201 wenn a new resource was created etc). Thats not easy to make when you handle it further way down your domain (you'd need result classes or throwing exceptions, but exceptions should be exceptional and the case above isn't exceptional but expected)

Comment: @Tseng, thanks for answer. I have a feeling, that role-based, claim-based and resource based authorization in .net core are usefull for very specific cases. Claims are linked to identity and resource-based auth is tightly linked to simple crud operations. So as I see if i'd need to realize role-based access to get (cRud) all the docs for admin and at the same time to realize resource based "get" for author.. It's difficult to realize by standart .net facilities using attributes and authorizationService.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply bake the authorization into your `_documentSender.SendAsync` call, e.g. something like:

```
await _documentSender.SendAsync(id, User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
```

The `NameIdentifier` claim is the user's id. In other words, you just pass in the current user's id to your method and do the authorization inside.